# W/VRSystemServiceManager(number): vr service is not alive

Tags: android, flutter, facebook-login

I have an app in production with Facebook Login implemented using flutter_facebook_login and it works fine on some Android devices (I think there's no problem with iOS devices as far as I tested it) but on others it crashes and the only error message I'm getting in the console is

`W/VRSystemServiceManager(  some number): vr service is not alive`

The quick google search doesn't gave me some relevant results.
Can anyone help me with this, please?

Ah.. when I tap more than once I get the following console output:

> I/HwPointEventFilter(  622): ACTION_DOWN has not handle

Edit:
I'm posting here the method I use to handle the Facebook Login:

```
    _loginWithFacebook() async {
        final result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);

        FacebookAccessToken myToken = result.accessToken;
        AuthCredential credential =
            FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: 
   myToken.token);

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
        try {
          firebaseUser =
              (await 
   FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
        } catch (e) {
          print(e.toString());
        } finally {
          final userToSubmit = User(
              email: firebaseUser.email,
              id: firebaseUser.uid,
              name: firebaseUser.displayName,
              owner: false,
              carAdded: false);

          DocumentReference dbRef = Firestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .document(firebaseUser.uid)
              .collection('usr')
              .document('profile');

          dbRef.get().then((snapshot) {
            snapshot.exists
                ? _goToHomeScreen(firebaseUser)
                : dbRef
                    .setData(userToSubmit.toJson())
                    .then(_goToHomeScreen(firebaseUser));
          });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems the vr service has nothing to do with this. The issue were with the key hash codes, but the problem were that on some Android versions the message with the error doesn't appear. 
Still have no idea why I have to add a new hash key every time I submit a new version of the app.